# LINQ expression to check against a collection and set a default value when the check fails

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SelectedListItem like so:

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetStatus()
{
    List<SelectListItem> msStatuses = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "New", Value = "50342"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "In Process", Value = "50343"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Approved", Value = "50345"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Rejected", Value = "50344"}};

    return msStatuses;
}
```

This is checked with the incoming value and set msStatus to the same when a match is found:

```
msStatus.Find(m => m.Value == UserRequest.Status.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

This works fine as long as the 'Status' property on UserRequest is one of the four.
When it's something other than the four it will throw a null exception.

In which case msStatus should be set to 'New', the first option, when the value to be checked
for is not one among the four.

How do I handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do it in a single line. Split in two lines with a null check. You can use either Find(as used here) OR FirstOrDefault. Both will return `null` if no matching condition is found. Calling `.Selected` on `null` will throw this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the result into a variable and check for null

```
var item = msStatus.Find(m => m.Value == UserRequest.Status.ToString());

if(item == null)
{
    // set selected item to New
    msStatus.Find(m => m.Value == "New").Selected = true; 
}
else 
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `FirstOrDefault` which will return null if it does not exists.

```
var statusItem = msStatus.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value == UserRequest.Status.ToString())

if (statusItem != null)
{
  // here you canaccess statusItem.Selected safety
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check for null or empty values of `Value` like so:

```
(m => String.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) || m.Value == UserRequest.Status.ToString());
```

If `Value` is empty or null then it'll be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

You can just make a flag wether its matching or not & then you can set it ::

```
bool IsstatusPresent= msStatus.Any(x=>m.Value == UserRequest.Status.ToString());

if(!IsstatusPresent)
{
   return msStatus.Find(m => m.Value == "New").Selected;
}
else 
{
   return  msStatus.Find(x=>m.Value == UserRequest.Status.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is `item` in the `else` branch?